# can't render <MapView/> from react-native-maps

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I am trying to show native map using the coords from the example and I get an error:

*note 
using ios and real device for debugging

ERROR:

```
Could not inset compass from edges 9
Could not inset scale from edge 
Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4
```

CODE:

```
class Map extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
render() {   
    console.log('map render')    
    return (
            <MapView 
            provider={null}
            initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
        />
    );
}}
```

project example: [HERE](https://github.com/obiwankenoobi/React-Map-Bug)

Comment: any error or warning?

Comment: yes the three first lines are the errors I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a problem with styling. I was able to fix it with this code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
        style={styles.map}
          provider={null}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
});
```